# Updating R to 3.5+ on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm looking to update R on our ubuntu 18.04 server to 3.5 or higher but I'm experiencing some difficulties.

Installing it via `install r-base` results in version 3.4.x, we need 3.5 or higher to run some specific scripts. I've also consulted this website: https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/, and attempted add the repository listed (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+`) but this results in the following errors:

`Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~c2d4u.team/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+'.`

`ERROR: '~c2d4u.team' user or team does not exist.`

At this point, I'm at a loss. I'm wondering if it's potentially a firewall issue? or is there a setting I need to change.

Answer (score -1):

What about downloading .deb(s) from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran40/ and installing them with dpkg / apt?